# Cannot set property 'id' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to bind `id` in my controller

```
 obj1["id"] = $scope.editableCourse.Modules[i].id;
 obj["id"] = $scope.editableCourse.Modules[i].Resourses[j].id;
```

but in run time, got an

> error: "Cannot set property 'id' of undefined".

How can I initialize "id" in my controller for the above cases.

Anyone suggest me a solution.

Comment: Either the modules or the resources is undefined.  You need to find out why.

Comment: The id is not the problem, the undefined object or controller is the problem.

Comment: You need to initialise the varibales $scope.editableCourse,obj1,obj etc.

Comment: Your `obj1` or `obj` is `undefined` therefor you can't set property on it. Depending on your case you could do `var obj = {}` to fix this

Comment: my question is how to declare  $scope.editableCourse.Modules[i].id in controller rest of the all declarations are perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `var obj={};` and `var obj1={};`

Whenever an object is declared its default value will be null like `var obj` or simply `obj` will be considered as `var obj=null or undefined;` and you cannot set any property like id for this undefined object.

so your code should be

```
 var obj = {};
 var obj1 = {};
 obj1["id"] = $scope.editableCourse.Modules[i].id;
 obj["id"] = $scope.editableCourse.Modules[i].Resourses[j].id;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: Give me a suggestion how to declare  $scope.editableCourse.Modules[i].id this reference variable